# What would be the best service for "append only" events in order for quick load times in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

I have a stream of events happening in the new CW Event Bridge that I need to get some statistics on from a REST API endpoint, a lambda function (python + pandas).

What is the best AWS service to store this data so that it's quick to load in a lambda function?

Here are the biggest cons of the things I've considered:

- CloudWatch logs is too slow
- CloudWatch insights only gives you last 1000 without pagination (and also is too slow)
- extended retention only covers last 7 days
- S3 does not have "append" operation
- DynamoDB will (probably) consume too much write capacity
- ElasticSearch seems a bit overkill (and requires an running cluster != serverless)

Answer (score 2):

[Kinesis Data Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/) looks like a good match for this use-case. 
If you only want to extract statistics out of your event streams, and you can use either SQL or Java, then you can also try out [Kinesis Data Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/).

Comment: I need them in format that can be ingested by a pandas Dataframe and NOT use SQL or Java

Comment: You can use Python + Panda with Kinesis Data Streams.